# SQL Server left join on recent exchange rate

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I ran into a problem with my T-SQL query. I have warehouse database, and I want to add currency exchange rates to my transactions, to see them in EUR and USD.

To do that, I am using Europe Central bank currency rates.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    Companys.Companys_name, 
    Warehouse_oper.Pavad_num, 
    [Items]![Quantity]*[Items]![Price] AS Expr1, 
    [Items]![Quantity]*[Items]![Price]*[Exchange_rates]![USD] AS Expr2
FROM 
    (Companys 
LEFT JOIN 
    (Exchange_rates 
RIGHT JOIN 
    Warehouse_oper ON Exchange_rates.Date = Warehouse_oper.Date) 
    ON Companys.Companys_num_d_b = Warehouse_oper.Companys_nr_d_b) 
LEFT JOIN 
    Items ON Warehouse_oper.Warehouse_oper_num_d_b = Items.Warehouse_oper_num_d_b;
```

Sorry if its hard to understand, because I translated all variables to English.

Anyways this query works fine, if `LEFT JOIN (Exchange_rates RIGHT JOIN Warehouse_oper ON Exchange_rates.Date = Warehouse_oper.Date`, but bank does not provide them on holidays, so on those dates I have NULL values.

How can I edit this query (I know it's messy, but it's from Access) to `SELECT` most recent available date?

I tried:

```
LEFT JOIN 
    (Exchange_rates RIGHT JOIN Warehouse_oper ON 
(SELECT TOP 1 Exchange_rates.Date FROM Exchange_rates WHERE
 Exchange_rates.Date <= Warehouse_oper.Date) = Warehouse_oper.Date)
```

but with no success.

Comment: Please post the full schema of the table `Exchange Rates` -- in all likelihood you'll need to alter that table to have a begin/end date on each exchange rate record to span the missing dates, then alter your join to be `warehouse_oper.date >= exhange_rates.begindate and warehouse_oper.date <= isnull(exchange_rates.enddate,getdate())` or something to that effect.

Comment: The table Exchange Rates table is simple:
Date | USD | RUB | GBP
so nothing really to see there

Comment: You have two options -- alter the table to populate a begin/end date, or write a CTE to fill the gaps, but I'd think the latter could impact performance on larger datasets.

Comment: The thing is I also tried:
"LEFT JOIN (Exchange_rates RIGHT JOIN Warehouse_oper ON Exchange_rates.Date <= Warehouse_oper.Date)"
But it returns more than 1 row, so it did not work. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Using `<=` like that would yield every exchange record prior to the warehouse date, hence duplication.  I think you have two options... fix your table or you'll need to write a CTE to bridge the gaps.  I suppose a 3rd option is to run a job daily which back-fills missing dates to have values equal to the day before.